# Issue with listing td's as inline-block elements in table in chrome

Tags: html, css, html-table

Has anyone any pointers for a problem that I am having in Chrome (iPhones too, when scaled) with the table structure in this email template?

All of the four td's have fixed width's but are not responding correctly. They should all stack inline as a list. Instead they are skewing and am struggling to work out the inheritance.

```
<tr>
    <td height="40" style=
    "float: none; clear: both; font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px; margin: 0px auto; display: inline-block;"
    width="50">
        <a href="http://cornermag.com/appstore"><img src=
        "http://www.cornermag.com/mailouts/issue6/getexcited/desktop/icon_facebook.png"
        style=
        "float: none; display: block; margin: 0px auto; clear: both;"></a>
    </td>

    <td height="40" style=
    "float: none; clear: both; font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px; margin: 0px auto; display: inline-block;"
    width="50">
        <a href="http://cornermag.com/appstore"><img src=
        "http://www.cornermag.com/mailouts/issue6/getexcited/desktop/icon_twitter.png"
        style="float: none;clear: both;display: block;margin: 0 auto;"></a>
    </td>

    <td height="40" style=
    "float: none; clear: both; font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px; margin: 0px auto; display: inline-block;"
    width="50">
        <a href="http://instagram.com/cornermagazine"><img src=
        "http://www.cornermag.com/mailouts/issue6/getexcited/desktop/icon_instagram.png"
        style="float: none;clear: both;display: block;margin: 0 auto;"></a>
    </td>

    <td height="40" style=
    "float: none; clear: both; font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px; margin: 0px auto; display: inline-block;"
    width="50">
        <a href="www.pinterest.com/cornermagazine/"><img src=
        "http://www.cornermag.com/mailouts/issue6/getexcited/desktop/icon_pintrest.png"
        style="float: none;clear: both;display: block;margin: 0 auto;"></a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Link: http://www.cornermag.com/mailouts/issue6/getexcited/new2.html

Any pointers would be a great help.

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but who do so many people who post table HTML in their question leave out the opening and closing `<table>` tags?

Comment: @j08691 Maybe because they have more stuff in there that's not relevant at all. The thead and all the headers, the tbody element, ... It all adds more and more indentation until you have to scroll to see anything at all. Just a guess however :)